# Why do tagged folders do not appear in open/save dialogs?

Tags: finder, bug, finder-tag

On my Mac, I use tags for both files and folders.

In the Finder, when clicking on the « tag view » in the sidebar, I see every file and folder which holds that tag, as expected.

However, for some reason, in Open and Save prompts, when I go in the same « tag view », folders are not shown, only files are.

I was wondering if it is a specific issue with my setup, or if it is a general bug in macOS ?

PS : I already have rebuilt Spotlight index.

On the screenshot below, top window is a generic Finder window. Bottom window is TextEdit open dialog. The latter do not show folders in Tag view.

[image: Top window is a generic Finder window. Bottom window is TextEdit open dialog. The latter do not show folders in Tag view.]

==================================================

Edit : After some additional trials, it seems it finally occurs only in Open dialogs, and in some apps only.

For instance, in Preview’s open dialog, the issue does not occur.
However, in Textedit, Pages, Numbers, the issue occurs in Open dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into finder>preferences>tags you will see that two tags have very similar colours, in my case, "work" and "orange". Try changing the colour of your "Projet" tag and see if they both the files change. If they don't then you might not have tagged your files correctly.

It seems like a silly answer but this has happened to me before that's why I am proposing this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but this is not the issue.

Comment: Can you try run this command to see if it comes up in terminal:
mdfind 'kMDItemUserTags=Projet'

Comment: Both files and folders are shown. But can't you test if you have this issue too ? I would not be surprised if it is a general bug in macOS and that we couldn’t do anything.

Comment: I have tried to recreate this but I cant. In both, my save and open prompts I can see both folders and files. 
What software are you using that presents that open prompt. I will try with that

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. After some additional tries, it looks like it is app-dependent. In TextEdit, Pages, Numbers, folders won’t show in Open dialogs, but are shown in Save dialogs. In Preview or Sublime Text, they are always shown.

Comment: @Tlokuus I have tested exactly what you mentioned and I can also confirm that it does not work for me.

Comment: Thank you for your test. Since no solution have been found, I’m afraid I have no reason to mark the question as answered.